# iOS: How to make a pod from my existing project? XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I have a project (framework) including pods, frameworks, bridging headers and many other files with various types. I want to make it accessible using cocoapods and can be easily add to other projects. I read many tutorials but non of them mentioned how to include all files of project and all dependencies.
I found this:

```
s.source_files = "YourDirectory/**/*.{swift}"
```

to add in podspec file but how to add my other files with many different file extensions?
How to properly make a big XCode framework a pod?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily include multiple wildcard expression in `s.source_files` in your Podspec, like this:

`s.source_files = "Dir1/**/*.swift", "Dir2/**/*.swift", "Dir3/**/*.{h,m,swift}"`

Once you've set up your new pod like this, you can include it using

`pod "YourNewPod", :path => ".../where/ever/your/pod/lives"`

into your respective projects.

Comment: `.mm` goes into the regular `source_files` list. For binary frameworks, there is the `vendored_frameworks` directive, for static libraries use `vendored_libraries`. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html for more details.